# How can I query the foreign key objects using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to learn about Entity Framework 6, and I am running into an issue, that I have been able to reproduce in a test project:

A `Movie` has a `Name`and a `Revenue`. A `Revenue` has a `GrossIncome`:

```
public class Movie
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Revenue Revenue { get; set; }
}

public class Revenue
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double GrossIncome { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use EF6 code-first to persist some data about movies in the database:

```
public class MovieContext: DbContext
{
    public MovieContext(): base("name=testDB") { }
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Revenue> Revenues { get; set; }
}
```

I start by inserting a new movie, with its associated revenue in the DB:

```
using (var context = new MovieContext())
{
    Revenue revenue = new Revenue()
                {
                    GrossIncome = 10
                };
    Movie movie = new Movie()
                {
                    Name = "foo",
                    Revenue = revenue
                };

    context.Movies.Add(movie);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can see in SQL Server that the tables are created, and that a `Movies.Revenue_Id` column has been created, with a foreign key relationship to `Revenue.Id`.

If I try to query it using SQL, it works fine:

```
SELECT Movies.Name, Revenues.GrossIncome
FROM Movies
LEFT JOIN Revenues ON Movies.Revenue_Id = Revenues.Id
```

returns

```
Name    GrossIncome
----------------------
foo         10
```

However, if I try to use Entity Framework to query the data:

```
using (var context = new MovieContext())
{
    List<Movie> movieList = context.Movies.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Movie Name: " + movieList[0].Name);

    if (movieList[0].Revenue == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Revenue is null!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(movieList[0].Revenue.GrossIncome);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The console reads:

```
Movie Name: foo     <- It shows that the query works, and that the data in the main table is fetched.
Revenue is null!    <- Even though the data in the DB is correct, EF does not read the data from the foreign key.
```

My question is simple: what am I doing wrong? How are the foreign key values supposed to be read?

Comment: Maybe you have lazy loading instead of eager loading? Try an Include() of the related object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just *include* the child entity you want to load:

```
using (var context = new MovieContext())
{
    List<Movie> movieList = context.Movies
                                   .Include(m => m.Revenue)   // ADD THIS INCLUDE
                                   .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Movie Name: " + movieList[0].Name);

    if (movieList[0].Revenue == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Revenue is null!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(movieList[0].Revenue.GrossIncome);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will load the movies - and also make sure that all the references to their respective `.Revenue` references have been loaded, too.

Comment: This works thanks. For future readers, turning the `Revenue` property `virtual` in the `Movie` class also solves the issue, as it enables lazy loading.

Comment: I would also like to add what I did, in addition to the comments above, is add the package:
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`
then under the ConfigureServices method where I add the dbcontext included a call to the `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` method:
`services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options=>options
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CONN"))
            );`

Comment: @jamesstap: this looks like you're using **EF Core** - this question was and is about the "original" EF6 on the full, classic .NET framework (**not** .NET Core)

Comment: @marc_s that is correct and notable, however this question resembled my issue the best I could find. just hoping this helps the next person.